# How to parse non-zero paded datetime string with strptime when leading zero is optional? Thanks

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, datetime-parsing

I've been trying to parse a datetime string in a file names with datetime.datetime.strptime().

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2023110912', "%Y%m%d%H%M")
datetime.datetime.strptime('202311912', "%Y%m%d%I%M")
datetime.datetime.strptime('202311912', "%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

I've tried search online for answers.
According this python documents link:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

in Notes No.9, it says:

When used with the strptime() method, the leading zero is optional for formats %d, %m, %H, %I, %M, %S, %j, %U, %W, and %V. Format %y does require a leading zero.

I'm expecting to get the result:
datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 12)

But, instead, I got:
datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 9, 1, 2)

if '%m, %H, %I, %M, %S' are leading zero optional, how to distinguish above two date-time?

my python version: 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)]

Did I miss something in the document? Can anybody help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do *you* know `202311912` means 2023-1-1 9:12 or 2023-11-9 1:02 if leading zeros are optional?  `strptime` takes two digits if they are there and are appropriate in range.  This is ambiguous.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you not to deal with any dates in an unpredictable format like that. There is always going to be a case where there is literally no way of knowing which date and time they're referring to. Let's play a game, when is this: 202311111? If you get it right in the first 3 guesses I'll write the rest of your project for you.

Comment: You already know Python(and no one) can't distinguish that two cases. The phrase "the leading zero is optional " implicitly assumes it does only when it can parse unambiguously, such as in the case of ```strptime('2023 3 15', '%Y %m %d')```.

Comment: That's 100% a bug in the data producer. Tell them to fix it and stop using their own custom formats when there are well know standards and conventions. Even humans can't tell whether `2023111` is January 11 or November 1. How could Python guess?

Comment: Use either the standard `YYYY-MM-DD` or the common convention `YYYYMMDD`